# facecolor kwarg for Matplotlib stacked histogram

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, histogram

I am having trouble controlling the color and linestyle of histogram plotted using Matplotlib's `hist` function with `stacked=True`. For a single non-stacked histogram, I have no trouble:

```
import pylab as P

mu, sigma = 200, 25
x0 = mu + sigma*P.randn(10000)

n, bins, patches = P.hist(
    x0, 20,
    histtype='stepfilled',
    facecolor='lightblue'
    )
```

However, when I introduce additional histograms,

```
import pylab as P

mu, sigma = 200, 25
x0 = mu + sigma*P.randn(10000)
x1 = mu + sigma*P.randn(7000)
x2 = mu + sigma*P.randn(3000)

n, bins, patches = P.hist(
    [x0,x1,x2], 20,
    histtype='stepfilled',
    stacked=True,
    facecolor=['lightblue','lightgreen','crimson']
    )
```

it throws the following error:

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "['lightblue', 'lightgreen', 'crimson']"
could not convert string to float: lightblue
```

Using the `color=['lightblue', 'lightgreen', 'crimson']` option does work, but I would like to have direct control of the fill and line colors separately while being able to use the named Matplotlib colors. I am using version 1.2.1 of Matplotlib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`facecolor` needs to be a single named color, not a list, but adding this 
after your `P.hist` usage might get the job done for you:

```
for patch in patches[0]: patch.set_facecolor('lightblue')
for patch in patches[1]: patch.set_facecolor('lightgreen')
for patch in patches[2]: patch.set_facecolor('crimson')
```

Comment: That did work, but is there no way to do this inline with `hist`?