# pyplot hist() separate linestyle for each stacked component

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a stacked histogram, where each stacked component has a different linestyle and color.  The `color` argument accepts as list with a color for each component. But the linestyle argument `ls` does not. Is there a way to control the face and linestyle of each stacked component separately?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.random(100)

# this works:
plt.hist([x,x], histtype='stepfilled', stacked=True, color=['r', 'b'])

# this does not:
plt.hist([x,x], histtype='stepfilled', stacked=True, color=['r', 'b'], ls=['-', '--'])
```

Ideally, I would like complete control over both the `color` and the `alpha` of both the face- and edgecolor of each stacked component.  Is that possible? I've tried playing around with the `fc` option, but that also does not accept a list.

I've also looked at this example [1], which shows this behaviour on `ax2`, but it appears very hacked. For example the following code yields a buggy result:

```
plt.hist([(0,1,1), (0,0,1)], histtype='step', stacked=True, fill=True)
```

There is the workaround of catching the `patches` and controlling them separately, like in this answer [2]. But I wonder if it is also possible directly from plt.hist()?

[1] http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_multihist.html

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/17517721/5064815

Answer (score 1):

You can [cycle through the linestyles](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html) in the same way as you can cycle through other parameters.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=(cycler('color', ['r', 'g', 'b']) +
                           cycler('linestyle', ['-', '--', ':']) + 
                           cycler('linewidth', [4,3,1])) )

x = np.random.random(100)
plt.hist([x,x*0.8,x*0.5], histtype='stepfilled', stacked=True )

plt.show()
```

Sidenote: I currently have no clue on why the cycle order is reversed in this example, i.e. the blue shape has a thick solid linestyle. But I guess that can be adapted as needed.

Comment: Thanks! But I guess this would change the `prop_cycle` for all subsequent plotting? So you would have to reset it after plotting the `hist`. I guess I would still be interested in a way of doing it more "directly".